# Can't Update Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, updates, update-manager

Whenever I try to update ubuntu 16.04 through the software updater I get an error saying "Failed to download repository information. Check your internet connection". I have tried several things that I found online but none of them work.

This is what I got after typing `grep -E '^\w' /etc/apt/sources.list` into the terminal.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu/ yakkety-security multiverse
```

Comment: May you please edit your question and paste the result of this command: `grep -E '^\w' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: If your internet is working properly, then try a different mirror.